# HTML inside of textView

Tags: swift

I want to paste HTML text(with p, br, bgcolor etc.) inside of textView. I did try the next:

```
var bodyText = NSAttributedString(data: body.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)

postBody.text = bodyText
```

postBody -> textView. But it prints the next error:

`Cannot assign a value of type 'NSAttributedString?' to a value of type 'String!'`

How can I correctly print it inside of textView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `text`, use `attributedText`.

```
postBody.attributedText = bodyText
```

Or, if you just want the text without the attributes, use `NSAttributedString`'s `string` property.

```
postBody.text = bodyText?.string
```